# Create new calendar with Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have set `user.read, calendars.readwrite` permisssion and can successfully authenticate. However  I get:

```
Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException : Code: ErrorInvalidRequest
Message: The OData request is not supported.
```

my tests looks like

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(request => {
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", _authenticationResult.AccessToken);
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}));

var user = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();

Console.WriteLine(user.Id + ": " + user.DisplayName + " <" + user.Mail + ">");
await graphClient.Me.Calendar.Request().CreateAsync(new Calendar(){Name = "test"});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually it was

```
await graphClient.Me.Calendars.Request().AddAsync(new Calendar(){Name = "test"});
```

and not

```
graphClient.Me.Calendar
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`await graphClient.Me.Calendar.Request().AddAsync(new Calendar(){Name = "test"});`

source : [Create calendar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-calendars?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp)

Comment: it does not compile the `AddAsync` method is not there.